# Is there a method to clear UILabel and UIImageView?

Tags: iphone

Is there another way to clear a `UILabel text` and a `UIImageView image` without doing something like this?

```
label.text = @"";
image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
```

Are there methods to execute these actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these also work if you just want to play around..

```
label.text =nil;
    image.image= nil;
```

what exactly do you wish to achieve....?

Comment: clearing the text and images only. do not wish to use the setText when there is a proper method out there.

Comment: the above method calls then are the best way to do it.. you don;t want anything in them , then this is what is to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (used to put `label.text =@"";`). This worked for me: `label.text =nil;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is old and already has a solution marked! but for Swift 3 I got it like this:

```
    self.label.text = "00:00:01"
    self.label.setNeedsLayout()
    self.label.text = "00:00:02"
    self.label.setNeedsLayout()
    self.label.text = "00:00:03"
    self.label.setNeedsLayout()
```